# How to integrate a REST API with SCCM for ServiceNow to consume it?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, servicenow, sccm

I created my rest api with node and typescript, but since I have no knowledge of SCCM, I need to understand if it would be possible to make this integration for ServiceNow to consume this api.

I need to create a dropdown list of free software in servicenow so that my company's employees can download it without having to open a ticket.

problem 1: company SN integration hub is Start

that's why the reason for creating this api, so that sccm can communicate with SN by sending commands (or something else I don't know) so that in SN the employee can download and install it without needing permission from support to complete the installation.

i have no idea what to do

edit ( Perhaps I have not clearly specified that the problem with my integration is understanding how to integrate my Rest API with SCCM/System Center, as my goal is to call the free license software that the company has and send it to ServiceNow when requeste )

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar - I have a node-based API gateway on our local network that I call from a [Scripted REST API](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/learn/learning-plans/tokyo/servicenow_application_developer/app_store_learnv2_rest_tokyo_scripted_rest_api_objectives).  Then, I can use an HTTP call to the "local" ServiceNow instance (something like `/api/namespace/api_id/resource_name`) from anywhere (UI Builder, Flow, Workflow, etc.).

In this example, I'm using a previously defined [REST Message](https://developer.servicenow.com/dev.do#!/learn/courses/tokyo/app_store_learnv2_rest_tokyo_rest_integrations/app_store_learnv2_rest_tokyo_outbound_rest_integrations/app_store_learnv2_rest_tokyo_creating_an_outbound_rest_message), but you could also follow the docs to set location, auth, headers, and params in code (if you don't want to define *yet another record*.

```js
function search( value ) {
    var rm = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2('rest_message_name', 'method_name');
    rm.setEccParameter('skip_sensor', 'true'); // prevent Discovery sensors from gobbling-up the ECC input

    // Set correlation ID for ECC, so we can find it in the logs
    var guid = gs.generateGUID();
    rm.setEccCorrelator(guid);

    rm.setQueryParameter('hostname', value);
    var result = rm.execute();
    var json = result.getBody();
    return JSON.parse(json);
}
```

Use this function in your Scripted REST API and pass/parse the results appropriately.

```js
var results = search('some_value');
res.setStatus(200);
res.setBody(results);
```

Comment: Hi Kerry, thank you so much for your generosity in answering my question. Perhaps I have not clearly specified that the problem with my integration is understanding how to integrate my Rest API with SCCM/System Center, as my goal is to call the free license software that the company has and send it to ServiceNow when requested .

Comment: @FelipeAlves, I think the code here will still work for you.  Instead of creating a scripted REST API, (to get data OUT of ServiceNow) you will use this in a Data Source (under System Import Sets).  Then you can schedule your import set to run on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

To ***import*** data into ServiceNow, you normally use Import Sets (Data Sources, Transform Maps, and schedules).  For the Data Source, specify a script like this:

```js
/* global gs, sn_ws */
(function loadData( import_set_table ) {

    var me = 'my_function_name';

    import_set_table.addColumn('hostname', 50);
    import_set_table.addColumn('serial', 50);
    import_set_table.addColumn('ip', 50);

    try {
        var rm = new sn_ws.RESTMessageV2('rest_message_name', 'method_name');
        rm.setEccParameter('skip_sensor', 'true'); // prevent Discovery sensors from gobbling-up the ECC input

        // Set correlation ID for ECC, so we can find it in the logs
        var guid = gs.generateGUID();
        rm.setEccCorrelator(guid);

        rm.setQueryParameter('hostname', value);
        var result = rm.execute();

        var json = result.getBody();
        var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
        var map = {
            hostname: parsed.hostname,
            serial: parsed.serial,
            ip: parsed.ip,
        };
        import_set_table.insert(map);

        gs.log('complete', me);
    }
    catch ( err ) {
        var errorMessage = err.getMessage() || err.message;
        gs.error('ERROR : ' + errorMessage, me);
    }

})(import_set_table);
```

Then you can use ***magic*** in your Transform Map to sync the values in the Import Set to a permanent table.  You can either map each row (normal) or ignore each row:

```js
/**
 * Do not import rows - all transformation is done onComplete
 */
(function transformRow() {
    /* nothing to import directly - actions happen onComplete */
    ignore = true;
})();
```

...and use an onComplete script (or [other type](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/sandiego-platform-administration/page/script/server-scripting/reference/r_MapWithTransformationEventScripts.html)) to manipulate the data by hand.  [This site](https://www.streyda.eu/post/transform-maps-in-servicenow) has a very easy to follow guide on how rows/sets are transformed.